# why Django admin short_description function not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

I am trying to make some changes in my django admin panel such as want to show "title" instead of "blog_tile" but I am not understanding why changes not reflecting.

```
class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ['blog_publish_time', 'blog_update_time']
    list_display = ['blog_title', 'blog_status',
                    'blog_publish_time', 'blog_update_time']

    def rename_blog_title(self, obj):
        return obj.blog_title[:10]
    rename_blog_title.short_description = "title"


admin.site.register(Blog, BlogAdmin)
```

where I am doing mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `blog_title`, not `rename_blog_title` in your `list_display`. You thus should refer to the method, not to the field of your `Blog` model:

```
class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ['blog_publish_time', 'blog_update_time']
    list_display = ['rename_blog_title', 'blog_status', 'blog_publish_time', 'blog_update_time']

    def rename_blog_title(self, obj):
        return obj.blog_title[:10]
    rename_blog_title.short_description = 'title'

admin.site.register(Blog, BlogAdmin)
```